# jquery join two URL queries

Tags: jquery, search, blogger

I have to work with a blogger site to setup a gallery based on querying posts with different labels. Blogger returns a maximum of 17 posts in any url label query, so I need to join two or more before writing (styling) the results for a multi-label (selectable) gallery. Here is the function being used so far for one URL query.

```
function loadContent(elementTarget, sourceURL, sourceElement) {
    $("" + elementTarget + "").hide();
    $("" + elementTarget + "").empty();
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    $("" + elementTarget + "").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&by-date=true " + sourceElement + "");
    $("" + elementTarget + "").load($("" + elementTarget + "").fadeIn('slow'));
    $("" + elementTarget + "").ready(function () {
        Shadowbox.setup("a.coverpreview", {
            viewportPadding: 40
        })
    });
}
```

`elementTarget` is the HTML element where the gallery results will be displayed and styled.

`sourceURL` is the substring to build the query; EXAMPLE: `'/search/?q=label:Adventure&max-results=75'`

**NOTE**: `max-results` has no effect in Blogger upon increasing results returned.

`sourceElement` is the element containing results returned by the URL query/search.

I need to append a second (and possibly third and fourth) set of results (and queries) to get up above 50 into the gallery for each label. Each subsequent query would have the '&start=17' added to it with increments of '17' each time. Each query would need to grab the 'sourceElement' content and add all such together to place in the 'elementTarget.'

I am a bit stumped as to how after fiddling with some options. Any suggestions or advice would be helpful. Here is the URL for gallery as it functions at present (right-click and open in new tab/windowif you wish).

http://www.ndauthorservices.com/p/gallery.html

Comment: So you want to show 50 at a time rather than the 17? or do you want to paginate somehow? Your intent is not fully clear.

Comment: Hi Mark. Sorry for the confusion. I would prefer the gallery to work without pagination, as that plus dynamically loaded and/or displayed content might make the implementation to complicated. --J.C.

Comment: Is it possible to change the link HTML? `<a href="javascript:loadContent('#storeContainer', '/search/?q=label:Covers-Adventure|label:Adventure&amp;max-results=75','#list-main')">Adventure</a>` to something else?

Comment: I am not sure I follow you, but I have tried (as you see here) to increase "max-results" to 75 and other amounts. The number of posts returned is still 17.  Hence why I need to get results in lots of 17, add them together, and then update "sourceElement."  

I have tried creating variables such as Content1, Content2, etc., targeting URL search results to fill them, and then chaining them together. I must have been doing something wrong (jquery novice here),  for the last query's results (17) were all that filled the element in the gallery page.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has some issues.  I will go over those then put a proposed answer after that with some suggestions for what should be better code as well as my assumptions that you CAN change the original links.

First off your function line by line with comments:

```
function loadContent(elementTarget, sourceURL, sourceElement) {
    $("" + elementTarget + "").hide();// do not need the double quotes

    $("" + elementTarget + "").empty();// do not need to "search the DOM again
    // new lines for above:
    var mytarget = $(elementTarget);// cache the initial
    mytarget.hide().empty();
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    mytarget.load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&by-date=true " + sourceElement);// did not need the last `+ ""` here
    // load again? no $("" + elementTarget + "").load($("" + elementTarget + "").fadeIn('slow'));
    mytarget.fadeIn('slow');//but the next part?  box after fadeIn?
    mytarget.ready(function () {
        Shadowbox.setup("a.coverpreview", {
            viewportPadding: 40
        })
    });
    // this change assumes you want to do it this way after the fadIn completes?
    // use a callback instead
    mytarget.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        Shadowbox.setup("a.coverpreview", {
            viewportPadding: 40
        });
    });
}
```

EDIT: Your function updated:

```
function loadContent(elementTarget, sourceURL, sourceElement) {
    var mytarget = $(elementTarget); // cache the initial
    mytarget.hide().empty();
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    mytarget.load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&by-date=true " + sourceElement);
    mytarget.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        Shadowbox.setup("a.coverpreview", {
            viewportPadding: 40
        });
    });
}
```

NOW, my proposed solution.  First I state the problem to make sure I have it clear:

1. When a user clicks a "type" we load "cover" pages 17 at a time up to a maximum of 50 of a given type.
2. When a user clicks a different type, we start over with that type and load up to 50, 17 at a time.
3. We can change the link markup to NOT have embedded JavaScript in it.
4. We can change the link markup to add some "data" properties and use them.

Proposed NEW markup for the links (one as an example):

```
<div><a class="actionlink" href="#" data-store='#storeContainer' data-load="empty" data-loadtype="Literary" data-search='/search/?q=label:Covers-Literary|label:Literary&max-results=75' data-list='#list-main'>Literary</a>
</div>
```

Add this markup somewhere: (we will use it to "load" chunks)

```
<div id="tempholder"></div>
```

Code:  put this in a document ready function

**EDIT:**
I did a bit of adjustment (my hurry up code had some issues) and created a simulation so you could see it working.  In my simulation I use some sample data rather than "load" something but you can see the effect.  See that here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/hexyLvwm/6/

I used that, then removed the comments and updated to what should be actual code here (no comments in it, no simulation):

EDIT: Updated code:

```
var lastLoaded = "";
var loadIncrement = 17;
var loadMaxCount = 50;
var loadCount = 0;
var tempHolder = $('#tempholder');
tempHolder.hide();  
function loadContent(elementTarget, sourceURL, sourceElement, me) {
    var displaytarget = $(elementTarget);
    displaytarget.hide();
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    var loadedElements = {};
    var useThese = {};
    var loadedElementsCount = 0;
    var urlRoot = "http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&by-date=true";
    var startpoint = '&start=';
    tempHolder.empty();
    if (lastLoaded != $(me).data('loadtype')) {
        lastLoaded = $(me).data('loadtype');
        loadCount = 0;
        displaytarget.empty()
        tempHolder.data("load", "empty");
    }

    if (loadCount && loadCount < loadMaxCount) {
        startpoint = '&start=' + loadCount;
    } else {
        startpoint = " ";
    }
    tempHolder.load(urlRoot + startpoint + sourceElement);
    loadedElements = tempHolder.find(sourceElement).children('.post-start.row');
    loadedElementsCount = loadedElements.length;
    if ((loadedElementsCount + loadCount) > loadMaxCount) {
        loadedElementsCount = loadMaxCount - loadCount;
        tempHolder.data("load", "loadcomplete");
    }
    loadCount = loadCount + loadedElementsCount;
    if (displaytarget.find(sourceElement).length) {
        useThese = tempHolder.find(sourceElement).children('.post-start.row').slice(0, loadedElementsCount);
        displaytarget.find(sourceElement).append(useThese);
    } else {
        useThese = tempHolder.find(sourceElement);
        displaytarget.append(useThese);
    }
    tempHolder.empty();
}

$('#fullcontentcontainer').on('click', '.actionlink', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var me = $(this);
    tempHolder.data("load", "empty");
    do {
        loadContent(me.data('store'), me.data('search'), me.data('list'), me);
    }
    while (tempHolder.data('load') != "loadcomplete" && loadCount !== 0);
    $(me.data('store')).fadeIn('slow', function () {
        Shadowbox.setup("a.coverpreview", {
            viewportPadding: 40
          });
    });
    tempHolder.data("load", "empty");
});
```

**EDIT: Use `$get`** snip to NOT put new data in DOM and use another method than your `.load` Just replace the function in the code:

```
function loadContent(elementTarget, sourceURL, sourceElement, me) {
    var displaytarget = $(elementTarget);
    displaytarget.hide();
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    var loadedElements = {};
    var useThese = {};
    var loadedElementsCount = 0;
    var urlRoot = "http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&by-date=true";
    var startpoint = '&start=';
    if (lastLoaded != $(me).data('loadtype')) {
        lastLoaded = $(me).data('loadtype');
        loadCount = 0;
        displaytarget.empty();
        tempHolder.data("load", "empty");
    }
    if (loadCount && loadCount < loadMaxCount) {
        startpoint = '&start=' + loadCount;
    } else {
        startpoint = " ";
    }
    var $elemR = {};
    $.get(urlRoot + startpoint, function (data) {
        var $elem = $('<div>').html(data);
        $elemR = $elem.find(sourceElement);
    });
    loadedElements = $elemR.find(sourceElement).children('.post-start.row');
    loadedElementsCount = loadedElements.length;
    if ((loadedElementsCount + loadCount) > loadMaxCount) {
        loadedElementsCount = loadMaxCount - loadCount;
        tempHolder.data("load", "loadcomplete");
    }
    loadCount = loadCount + loadedElementsCount;
    if (displaytarget.find(sourceElement).length) {
        useThese = $elemR.find(sourceElement).children('.post-start.row').slice(0, loadedElementsCount);
        displaytarget.find(sourceElement).append(useThese);
    } else {
        useThese = $elemR.find(sourceElement);
        displaytarget.append(useThese);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84345/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-schultheiss-jquery-join-two-url-queries).